# How do I remove commas from an array and make it a single string variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried combining the elements of an array (i.e. [1, 6, 3, 7, 3] to "16373") by removing the commas and reversing it but I am unable to remove the commas. My code:

```
var res = [1, 6, 3, 7, 3];
res.toString();
res.reverse();
alert(res);
```

Comment: You have clearly not read any information about Arrays in Javascript. I would suggest reading through some of the MDN documentation or reading through some tutorials.

Comment: What role does "reversing it" have in what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
var str = res.join(""); // "16373"
```

The [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) call will join all the elements of the array by the specified string, in this case empty string and returns that string.

Comment: Thankyou! But After doing that I am not able to reverse my string!
    str.reverse();
is not working.

Comment: If you want to do that, then do `res.reverse().join("");`

Comment: @AyushMainali: strings don't have a reverse method. After you spent some time learning the standard API, things like this won't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [JOIN method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

The join() method joins all elements of an array into a string.

```
res.join("");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MjELW/23/)

To reverse the string you can try like this:

```
res.reverse().join("")
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MjELW/24/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you have is an Array of numbers. In order to get all the numbers together, you can join them like this

```
var res = [1, 6, 3, 7, 3];
console.log(res.join(""));
# 16373
```

But the result will be a string. If you want to convert that to a number, you can simply use unary `+` operator, like this

```
var res = +[1, 6, 3, 7, 3].join("");
console.log(res, typeof res);
# 16373 'number'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using join()

```
var res=[1,6,3,7,3];
alert(res.join(''));//prints 16373
```